# Como ejecuto dos archivos de C# en un mismo proyecto

Tags: c#

estoy aprendiendo a usar C# y quiero hacer un juego de una trivia, me gustaria tener distintos archivos como por ejemplo un archivo con los datos del jugador, otro archivo con las preguntas y otro archivo donde guarde las respuestas, y luego ejecutar todos juntos, pero no se como hacerlo.

Por el momento solo tengo 2 archivos, en los cuales solo hago una impresion de caracteres por consola utilizando

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World in Question file!");
```

pero me gustaria que se ejecutaran distintos archivos en **un orden estilo cascada.**

Este es es el archivo ***Program.cs***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo ***Question.cs***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema no es que tengas muchos archivos sino que en una aplicacion de consola solamente puedes tener un punto de entrada, es decir, un método `static void Main`. En ése caso tienes dos por lo cuál no compila.

Para lograr lo que deseas, podrías crear varias clases, una en cada archivo (aunque no es necesario pero sí una excelente práctica) y utilizarlas dentro del método Main.

Ejemplo:

```cs
// Archivo PlayerData.cs

using System;
namespace proyectoa
{
   public class PlayerData
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public void Run()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Cual es tu nombre?");
         Name = Console.Readline();
      }
   }
}
```

```cs
// Archivo Questions.cs

using System;
namespace proyectoa
{
   public class Questions
   {
      public string Answer { get; set; }
      public void Run()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Cuanto es 2+2?");
         Answer = Console.Readline();
      }
   }
}
```

Así, dentro de tu método Main puedes hacer uso de ellas:

```cs
// Archivo Program.cs

namespace proyectoa
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
         data.Run();

         Questions ques = new Questions();
         ques.Run();
      }
   }
}
```

Si requires utilizar las propiedades de un objeto en otro hay varias maneras de hacerlo. Una de ellas es guardar una referencia de un objeto como un atributo. Por ejemplo, si quisieramos usar el nombre del jugador dentro de Questions:

```cs
// Archivo Questions.cs

using System;
namespace proyectoa
{
   public class Questions
   {
      private PlayerData _playerData;
      public string Answer { get; set; }
      
      public Questions(PlayerData playerData)
      {
         _playerData = playerData;
      }

      public void Run()
      {
         // Puedes utilizar el nombre del jugador
         Console.WriteLine($"Cuanto es 2+2 {_playerData.Name}?");
         Answer = Console.Readline();
      }
   }
}
```

Y dentro de Program.cs:

```cs
// Archivo Program.cs

namespace proyectoa
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
         data.Run();

         Questions ques = new Questions(data);
         ques.Run();
      }
   }
}
```

Te recomiendo estudies los conceptos de clases, objetos, encapsulación para que puedas comprenderlo mejor y llegar a mejores soluciones.

Comment: Te hago una consulta, como puedo leer una variable que esta en un archivo, leerla en otro?

Comment: Por ejemplo, tengo en CharacterSetting la variable "Puntaje", me gustaria que cuando la persona acierte, se le sume 10, pero no se como hacer para llamar a esa variable en el archivo de Questions.cs

Comment: Edité la respuesta

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Carlos, sos un geniol!